# Login code is not working on my code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This my model page where I make database connectivity. Registration from working fine but login form not working. Even don't show any message too. I not good in codeigniter. Please let me know where is wrong.

Below is my code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('user_name')!="")
        {
            $this->welcome();
        }
        else
        {
            $data['title']= 'Home';

            $this->load->view("index.php", $data);
        }
    }
    function welcome()
    {
        $data['title']= 'Welcome';
        $this->load->view('header_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('welcome_view.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view',$data);
    }
    public function login()
    {
        alert("gregrtg");
        $email=$this->input->get('email');
        $password=$this->input->get('password');

        $result=$this->user_model->login($email,$password);
        $data['title']= 'Register successfully!';
 //if($result)
 //$input = '/application/views/vendor-profile.php'; // you can't access view directly. call this view from a controller.
   //     echo json_encode(array("next_url"=>$input));
        if($result) $this->load->view("vendor-profile.php",$data);
        else        $this->index();
    }
    function thank()
    {       

        $this->user_model->add_user();
        $data['title']= 'Register successfully!';
        $this->load->view("index.php", $data);

    }
    public function registration()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'User Name', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|xss_clean|callback_check_user_ci');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_mobile','User Mobile','trim|required|min_lenght[10]|max_length[10]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Your Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[4]|max_length[32]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('con_password', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required|matches[password]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->user_model->add_user();
            $data['title']= 'Register successfully!';
            $this->thank();
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $newdata = array(
        'user_id'   =>'',
        'user_name'  =>'',
        'user_email'     => '',
        'logged_in' => FALSE,
        );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($newdata);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->index();
    }
    public function check_user_ci()
    {
        $usr=$this->input->post('user_name');
        $result=$this->user_model->check_user_exist($usr);
            if($result)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', 'User Name already exit.');
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
    }
    public function check_user()
    {
        $usr=$this->input->post('name');
        $result=$this->user_model->check_user_exist($usr);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "false";

        }
        else{

            echo "true";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

this is my controller file....

```
<!-- Modal Popup Sign Up and Login Start Here -->

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up / Login</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab Start Here -->
      <div role="tabpanel"> 

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#signup" aria-controls="signup" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="commom-icon signup"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#login" aria-controls="login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span class="commom-icon login"></span> Log In</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="signup">
           <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); ?>
              <?php echo form_open("user/thank"); ?>
               <div class="signUpForm">
                <div class="form-group" id="title1">

                <?php echo $title; ?>
                </div>
                </div>
              <div class="signUpForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputText">Enter Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo set_value('user_name'); ?>" /><div id="usr_verify" class="verify" style="display:none;"> Invalid User</div>
                <div id="usr_verify1" class="verify" style="display:none;">User Field should not be empty!</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputText">Enter Mobile No.</label>
                <input type="text" id="mobile_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." name="mobile_number" value="<?php echo set_value('mobile_number'); ?>" /><span id="mobile_verify" class="verify"  style="display:none;">Invalid Mobile Number</span><span id="mobile_verify1" class="verify"  style="display:none;"> Mobile number should not be Empty</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputText">Enter Email</label>
                  <input type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." name="email_address" value="<?php echo set_value('email_address'); ?>" /><span id="email_verify" class="verify"style="display:none;">Invalid EmailID</span><span id="email_verify1" class="verify"  style="display:none;"> EmailID should not be Empty</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
                 <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" /><span id="password_verify" class="verify" style="display:none;">Password Should not be empty</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="con_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Confirm Password" name="con_password" value="<?php echo set_value('con_password'); ?>" /><span id="confrimpwd_verify" class="verify" style="display:none;">Confirm Password Should not be empty!</span>
                <span id="confrimpwd_verify1" class="verify" style="display:none;">Confirm Password and password not matching!</span>
                 </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12" align="right">
             <input type="button" id="formsubmit" class="greenButton" value="Submit" />
                <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>-->
                </div>
              </div>
           <?php echo form_close(); ?>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="login">
            <?php echo form_open("user/login");?>
              <div class="loginForm">
              <div class="form-group" id="myDiv">
              <?php echo $title;?>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="useremail" placeholder="Enter email" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div id="emailerror" style="display:none;">Email Field is required!</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1"> Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userpassword" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo set_value('userpassword'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div id="passworderror" style="display:none;">Password field is required!</div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 mb20 forgetBtn" align="left"> <span class="label label-warning cp">Forget Password ! ! !</span> </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="check" value="Login"> 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
<div id="div1"></div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            <form>
              <div class="fgtForm hide">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Email address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 mb20 backLoginBtn" align="left"> <span class="label label-warning cp">Back to Login</span> </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6" align="right">
                  <input type="button" class="greenButton" value="Submit" onclick="validate()" />
                    <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Click To Process</button>-->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Tab End Her --> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Popup Sign Up and Login End Here -->



<script type="text/javascript">
$("#formsubmit").click(function(){
  var oxmlHttpSend;

if($("#user_name").val().length == 0)
{
   $("#usr_verify1").show();
}
var mobile=$("#mobile_number").val();
 var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/; 
        if(mobile!="")
        {
                    if(mobile.match(phoneno))
                    {
                      $("#mobile_verify").hide();
                      $("#mobile_verify1").hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $("#mobile_verify").show();
                      $("#mobile_verify1").hide();
                    }
        }
        else
        {
          $("#mobile_verify1").show();
          $("#mobile_verify").hide();
        }
var email = $("#email_address").val();
  if(email!="")
  {
     var regex = /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)@([0-9a-zA-Z]([-_\\.]*[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)[\\.]([a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;
        if(!regex.test(email))
            {
                $("#email_verify").show();
                 $("#email_verify1").hide();
            }
        else{
             $("#email_verify").hide();
            }
  }
  else
  {
    $("#email_verify1").show();
     $("#email_verify").hide();
  }

var password=$("#password").val();
if(password=="")
{
  $("#password_verify").show();
}
else
{
   $("#password_verify").hide();
}
var con_password=$("#con_password").val();
if(con_password=="")
{
  $("#confrimpwd_verify").show();
}
else
{
  $("#confrimpwd_verify").hide();
}
if(password!=con_password)
{
  $("#confrimpwd_verify1").show();
}
else
{
  $("#confrimpwd_verify1").hide();
}
 if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined")
    {
        oxmlHttpSend = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
       oxmlHttpSend = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    if(oxmlHttpSend == null)
    {
       alert("Browser does not support XML Http Request");
       return;
    }

    var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/thank";
   url += "?name=" + $("#user_name").val() + "&mobile=" + $("#mobile_number").val() +"&email=" + $("#email_address").val() +"&password=" + $("#password").val();
   oxmlHttpSend.open("GET",url,true);
  oxmlHttpSend.send(url);


});
</script>
<script >


 $("#check").click(function()
 {
      var df1=$("#useremail").val();
      var df2=$("#userpassword").val();
       if(df1=="")
        {
          $("#emailerror").show();
          $("#passworderror").hide();
        }
      if(df2=="")
        {
          $("#emailerror").hide();
          $("#passworderror").show();
        }
      if(df1=="" && df2=="")
        {
          $("#emailerror").show();
          $("#passworderror").show();
        }   
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  url="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/user/login";
  url+="?email= "+$("#useremail").val()+"&password= "+$("#userpassword").val();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}


</script>
```

main view page where login form is not working

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function login($email,$password)
    {
        $this->db->where("email",$email);
        $this->db->where("password",$password);

        $query=$this->db->get("user");
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach($query->result() as $rows)
            {
                //add all data to session
                $newdata = array(
                        'user_id'       => $rows->id,
                        'user_name'     => $rows->username,
                        'user_mobile'   => $rows->mobile,
                        'user_email'    => $rows->email,
                        'logged_in'     => TRUE,
                   );
            }
                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
                return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function add_user()
    {
       $this->db->where("email",$this->input->get('email'));
        $query=$this->db->get("user");
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

        $data=array(
            'username'=>$this->input->get('name'),
            'mobile'=>$this->input->get('mobile'),
            'email'=>$this->input->get('email'),
            'password'=>md5($this->input->get('password'))
            );
        $this->db->where("username",$data['username']);
        $query=$this->db->get("user");

        $result=$this->db->insert('user',$data);
        if($result->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
                   if($query->num_rows()>0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }
    }
    public function check_user_exist($usr)
    {

        $this->db->where("username",$usr);
        $query=$this->db->get("user");
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: ok give me time i make it simple

Answer (score 0):

`alert("gregrtg");` is a function for JavaScript and not for PHP.